# Question tabs are not rendering properly in Firefox on MacOS

Tags: support, design, tabs, questions-tabs

Seems like there is some weirdness rendering the question bar in Mac Firefox. Safari seems to work fine and so does Firefox in Windows.

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100313-r2mjsawkp39c4ffd8c362fx8db.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100313-r2mjsawkp39c4ffd8c362fx8db.png)

Comment: Ugh. I love FF and am glad Mac folks can use it, too, but man, it's starting to take on a bit of an IE5/Mac flavor.

Comment: See that here too (FF v3.6, Mac OS 10.5.8). Hasn't been bothering me, though.

Comment: FF + Mac doesn't seem to have freehand circles either :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the same *wrong* rendering on Windows and Firefox v3.6,
if you change the zoom level, ie if you zoom out with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> -

Comment: Indeed, the screen capture in the question seems to indicate downsizing (either by Firefox, or before posting the image). @Igor, did you try pressing Command-0 (zero) to reset to 100% zoom?

Comment: I have pressed Cmd-0 and that was the result. I did see different results with different zoom levels however. The image appears resized due to being in the post. If you view the image by itself (i.e. "View Image") it's normal size.

Comment: Huh, seems OK now. I think either me or my computer had gremlins. Probably me...

Answer (score 0):

I don't exhibit this behavior.

Firefox 3.6 / OS X 10.6.2

Comment: Firefox 3.5.8 + OS X 10.6.2 looks fine too.

Answer (score 0):

This only happens when zoomed out. Zoom back to 100% and it's fine.

I doubt there's anything the StackOverflow team can do about this via their code; it's clear that Firefox is simply screwing up borders upon being zoomed out.